# Triggering observer.error yields console error

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a modal service and component that is called by other components in my Angular app. The user should be able to trigger one action if they click the Cancel button, and another action if they click Ok.

The modal service creates and subscribes to the modal component observable. If they click ok, it executes the calling component's actions with `observer.next()`. If the user clicks cancel, it either closes the modal without executing anything, or triggers another method. Previously I had the cancel path kill the observer with `observer.complete()`, but this just closes out and doesn't enable the user to complete actions on click of the cancel button. Because of that, it seems like it would be better to have the observer throw an error. I implemented this and the Ok/Cancel paths work as expected, but I now see a console error.

```
    this.modalDialogRef = this.dialog.open(ModalComponent, {
      // the modal properties
    });

    return new Observable((observer: Observer<string | null>) => {
      // this next line does not produce a console error,
      // but doesn't let the user execute some actions on cancel click, because it just closes out and doesn't return a value.
      // this.modalDialogRef.componentInstance.onClickCancel.subscribe(() => observer.complete());
      this.modalDialogRef.componentInstance.onClickCancel.subscribe(() => observer.error(null));
      this.modalDialogRef.componentInstance.onClickOk.subscribe((value?: string) => observer.next(value));
    });
```

The calling component calls into the modal service like this.

```
      this.modalService.prompt('', '', this.modalOptions)
        .subscribe(() => {
          // happy path
        }, () => console.log('error path'));
```

The onClickCancel method inside of the modal component looks like this.

```
  cancel(): void {
    this.modalRef.close();
    this.modalRef.afterClosed().subscribe(() => this.onClickCancel.next());
  }
```

Here is the error message I see if I click the cancel button.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ngOriginalError' of null
    at getOriginalError (core.js:1663)
    at ErrorHandler.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ErrorHandler._findOriginalError (core.js:1737)
    at ErrorHandler.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ErrorHandler.handleError (core.js:1714)
    at Object.next (core.js:4311)
    at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (core.js:3551)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:192)
```

Why does setting up the cancel path this way create a console error, and how can I get rid of it?

Edit: throwing a new Error() inside of `Observer.error()` as suggested in the comments just throws a different console error: "Error at modal.service.ts".

Comment: pass an actual `Error` object instead of `null`.  There is angular code that expects the observer error channel to contain actual objects.  So try `observer.error(new Error())` instead of `observer.error(null)`

Comment: @Brandon When I do that, the console error says "Error at modal.service.ts". I'm guessing that in order to get console errors regardless of what I pass to the observer.error, it means that I'm not catching it properly in the calling component. But since I already have the second argument inside of the calling component's .subscribe(), I don't know how else I would catch it.